# Change path to manage.py when running Git Push Heroku Master

Tags: django, heroku, manage.py, askbot

I just deployed Askbot forum to heroku successfully, but sometimes when running 'git push heroku master', the automatic collectstatic process fails (to me it looks like a random failure), prompting:

`-----> Python app detected`

```
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
   Cleaning up...

-----> Preparing static assets
   Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
   $ heroku run python ./askbot/setup_templates/manage.py collectstatic --noinput`
```

Well I don't really know if that's the problem, but the `manage.py` in `.askbot/setup_templates/` contains the app's native version of the file, not the one I'm using for deployment, which is located in the app's root.

How could I make `git push heroku master` use the right `manage.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path in your [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#declare-process-types-with-procfile). Typically its something like this:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --log-file -
```

Adjust it:

```
# from:
web: gunicorn .askbot/setup_templates/yourApp.wsgi

# to: 
web: gunicorn .askbot/yourApp.wsgi
```

to check if the path was indeed your problem run this from the terminal:

```
heroku run python ./manage.py collectstatic

# or 

heroku run python ./yourApp.wsgi collectstatic
```

Comment: Procfile is executed after the manage.py collectstatic command I was talking about, My priority was to fix that call. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Deleting or renaming Manage.py in `askbot/setup_templates/` solved the problem.

Git Push Heroku Master never fails whan running `collectstatic` ever after.

so I believe that for some reason, probably because of sys.path configuration sometimes 
Git Push Heroku Master first discovered and used  `./askbot/setup_templates/manage.py` instead of `./manage.py` (which was the right one), and encountered an ImportError.